# How to determine which expression is true when multiple expressions are checked in an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I was wondering (pretty much just out of curiosity) if there's a way in jquery to determine, in an if statement with multiple checks like this one

```
if (expression1 || expresison2 || expression3){
   ...
}
```

which one (or ones) are the truthy and if there's a param or something to get it inside the if statement.

for instance:

```
if(expression1 || expression2 || expression3){
   console.log( { the truthy expression } ) // Log in console: expression1
}
```

This, again, is just for my curiosity as i couldn't find anything online. I know i can split the statements or have this checked differently

Comment: Other than testing the expressions again individually, no.

Comment: just do `if...else if...else if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no jQuery here, only Javascript. One option, though an ugly one, would be to assign to a variable inside the `if` condition, and then print out that variable:

```js
const a = '';
const b = 'foo';
const c = false;
let result;
if(result = (a || b || c)){
  console.log(result);
}
```

If at all possible, though, assign to `result` *outside* if the `if` statement, many linters will complain about assignment inside an `if`:

```js
const a = '';
const b = 'foo';
const c = false;
const result = a || b || c;
if(result){
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: This gives you the truthy result, the OP appears to want the truthy property name, i.e. `a`